# Need to find position of a character in a text/sequence file?

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

For example I have the sequence below in a text file called sequence_test:
AAAAATGATGATGTGATTAAATTTTTGAGAGTGATATGATATTTTTATAGATATGAGTAGGATAGTATAGATAG

I want to find the position number of all "A" characters and return it as an output. What command do I use to do that?

Comment: Do you want to get the position(s) by line or the byte offset(s) of all the file?

Answer (score 1):

```bash
$ fold -w 1 file | sed -n '/A/='
1
2
3
4
5
8
11
16
19
20
21
28
30
34
36
39
41
47
49
51
53
56
59
62
64
67
69
71
73
```

This uses `fold` to convert each character of the input in `file` to its own line, and `sed` is then used to output the line numbers of each line with an `A` on them.

The `sed` command could be replaced by any number of other commands, for example, `awk '/A/ { print NR }'`.

Using `awk` exclusively is also possible, obviously.  The following uses `substr()` to extract each character in turn and output the character's position if it's an `A`:

```bash
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= length; ++i) if (substr($0,i,1) == "A") print i }' file
```

Would you want all the numbers in a comma-separated list, pass the result of the above through `paste -s -d, -`.

Comment: This worked. Thanks!

Comment: @user19194612 Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer marks the issue as resolved.

Comment: Since `substr` is one-origin, you want the for to run while `i<=length`. In _gnu_ awk (gawk) there is also `awk -F '' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i=="A") print i}' file`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for spotting that. I've fixed it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -ne '.from.put for m:g/A/;' file
```

If you just have a single-line file, you can use the simplistic code above. The `.from` call tells you where the match starts (zero-indexed). Alternatively, you can use `.to` to return where the match ends. Either way, positions are returned, one-per-line.

If you have a multi-line file, you'll want to know the position of matching characters *on each line*. The code below creates an array-of-hashes, which does just that:

```
~$ raku -ne 'state %a; state $i; $i++; for m:g/A/ { %a.push: $i => $_.from }; END .say for %a.sort;'   file
```

Sample Input (OP's example nucleotide sequence, twice, with a blank line in-between):

```
AAAAATGATGATGTGATTAAATTTTTGAGAGTGATATGATATTTTTATAGATATGAGTAGGATAGTATAGATAG

AAAAATGATGATGTGATTAAATTTTTGAGAGTGATATGATATTTTTATAGATATGAGTAGGATAGTATAGATAG
```

Sample Output:

```
1 => [0 1 2 3 4 7 10 15 18 19 20 27 29 33 35 38 40 46 48 50 52 55 58 61 63 66 68 70 72]
3 => [0 1 2 3 4 7 10 15 18 19 20 27 29 33 35 38 40 46 48 50 52 55 58 61 63 66 68 70 72]
```

Generally, `.say` is used in Raku to provide human-readable output; but it's recommended to use `.put` for production since `.say` will truncate long sequences (greater than 99 elements).

Note from above: To just return results for individual lines (let's say the first line), change the code above `END .say for %a.sort`  to instead just call the `<1>` key (thereby returning the associated values), as in: `END .put for %a<1>;`

Sample Output ( using `END .put for %a<1>;` ):

```
0 1 2 3 4 7 10 15 18 19 20 27 29 33 35 38 40 46 48 50 52 55 58 61 63 66 68 70 72
```

https://raku.org